# Having problems with adoTable

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i would like to be able to ensure that if a table (in this case `adotHours`) enters Edit or insert mode and the user clicks the save button but accidentally posts the same value under the `Hours` column as was already entered, a message appears `Please enter another value`, otherwise if the user enters a different value, another piece of code is used.

I have tried the following method but it doesn't work,- whatever the user enters the message `Please enter another value` appears.

```
procedure TfrmLabour.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  i,j, t: String;
begin
  Edit1.Text := adotHours['Hours'];
  j :=  Edit1.Text;
  adotHours.Post;
  Edit2.Text := adotHours['Hours'];
  t := Edit2.Text;
  if t = j then 
    showmessage ('Please enter another value')
  else begin.....
end;
```

while i know it may not be the most elegant code, my thinking was that once the value had been posted to `adotHours` `Hours` through the connected `DBgrid`, if it was a different value to before `t` would become the new value and therefore `adotHours['Hours']` would be different and allow the `else begin`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking the entered value against the [`OldValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TField.OldValue) property.

```
adotHours.FieldByName('Hours').OldValue
```

Comment: And check OldValue within beforepost event, much easier and less code than OP with all of the extra assignments etc...

Answer (score 2):

`adotHours.FieldByName('Hours').NewValue` will be `Unassigned` if the field value is not modified. In that case, OldValue will contain the (unmodified) value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
if adotHours.FieldByName('ItemName').OldValue = 
  adotHours.FieldByName('ItemName').Value then
  Showmessage(Please enter another value');
```

But as for me, it would be better to put this code in event `adotHours.BeforePost` and call the `abort` procedure if values are the same - in other case, when user changes value and clicks on other row on grid - it cause Post in dataset, and you may miss your check in button click.